# F#: more elegant way to multiply negative numbers in a list

Tags: functional-programming, f#

Sorry for stupid question, I'm really new in f#.
I want to write a function to multiply negative numbers in a list. But now my function isn't perfect.

```ml
let rec mulOfNegs = function
    | [] -> 0
    | x::t when x < 0 -> x * if mulOfNegs t <> 0 then mulOfNegs t else 1
    | _::t -> mulOfNegs t

mulOfNegs [2;3;-1;-2;-3]
```

Of course, there are many ways to optimize the function (create more then one function, use some variables etc), but I don't exactly know which one is better and more "functional".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The product of an empty set is 1 not 0.
2. You are working around this with a hack (recognizing that if `mulOfNegs t = 0` then it's wrong and should be replaced with 1). The implementation performs badly since it evaluates mulOfNegs twice, making your function O(2^n) rather than O(n).
3. Once you correct 1. and remove the hack, you should have a working function. But you could make it more comprehensible by splitting in two:

```ml
let rec productOfNegs = function
    | [] -> 1
    | x::t ->
        if x < 0 then x * productOfNegs t else productOfNegs t

// Alternatively
let productOfNegs =
    let product = List.fold (*) 1
    List.filter (fun x -> x < 0) >> product
```